# How to split a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, split, base64

I have a long string resulted from encoding a binary file -an image file- (in base 64). Is there a particulary method (or rule) I should follow when spliting it?
Edit:
I want to write the string to a xml file, but in order to do this I must split it in smaller chunks.
Edit2:
I would like to split it by length (I think that is more appropriate in this case).
Thank you.

Comment: How do you want to split it? What delimeter would you want to use?

Comment: There are many ways of splitting strings in PHP. You need to be a little more specific of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to write the string to a xml file that is generated by a php script and I can write it if I don't split it in smaller chunks.

Comment: You need to tell us how do you want to split the string. By length or at a character sequence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [`chunk_split()`](http://php.net/manual/function.chunk-split.php), since you do base64 encoding. (Assuming you do *encoding*, since you can't embed *decoded* base64 data in XML files)

Comment: Yes, i was talking about encoding. My bad. Thanks Boldewyn.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) or [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) as appropriate. All data in PHP is technically binary, even character data. If your data is multibyte character data (eg UTF-8) you'll need extra steps to correctly handle that.

Also binary strings may need processing with [`unpack()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php).

Answer (score 0):

[chunk_split (string $body  [, int $chunklen  [, string $end  ]] )](http://php.net/chunk_split)